# APCU doesn't store in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, apcu

I'm using APCU for data caching. It was working fine until I've updated server. After updating I have those versions:
Apache - 2.4.10
PHP - 5.6
APCU - 4.0.11

Now nothing is stored in cache. When I run php -r 'apcu_store("Test", "Test value");' it returns "1" but consequent apcu_fetch("Test") returns nothing.

What could be broken?

APCU is configured as following:

```
APCu Support => Enabled
Version => 4.0.11
APCu Debugging => Disabled
MMAP Support => Enabled
MMAP File Mask =>
Serialization Support => php
Revision => $Revision: 328290 $
Build Date => Dec  1 2016 12:26:37

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 2048M => 2048M
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.writable => /tmp => /tmp
```